# Local cluster k8s not added in Rancher - "No secret assigned to service account cattle-system/rancher"

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Local K8s - 1.24.2
Rancher - 2.6.6

The rancher is installed on a virtual machine on the same subnet as K8s.

Install rancher single with volume:

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /opt/rancher:/var/lib/rancher --privileged rancher/rancher:latest
```

After im trying to add existing cluster, because im havent no self-signed certificates, im use:

```
% curl --insecure -sfL https://<My-IP>:8446/v3/import/dtdsrjczmb2bg79r82x9qd8g9gjc8d5fl86drc8m9zhpst2d9h6pfn.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

> namespace/cattle-system created serviceaccount/cattle created
> clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/cattle-admin-binding
> created secret/cattle-credentials-3035218 created
> clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/cattle-admin created
> deployment.extensions/cattle-cluster-agent created
> daemonset.extensions/cattle-node-agent created

ALL need things are created.

Then k8s trying to start pod and pod cant start with error - "**starting" time="2022-07-11T13:19:14Z" level=fatal msg="looking up cattle-system/cattle ca/token: no secret exists for service account cattle-system/cattle**""

I checked the cattle service account doesn't have the secret. Looks the function above expecting ServiceAccountRootCAKey and ServiceAccountTokenKey. How can I get this info from my Rancher server? Can I add this secret into the service account, will that solve the issue?

Comment: I had the same issue and after update to `v2.7-head` version my issue solved.